# Clonezilla failure when cloning and shrinking with a SSD destination

Tags: partitioning, clone, clonezilla

I'm trying to replace a HDD with a SSD of slightly smaller size. The machine runs Windows 7 and has two partitions.

The source HDD is 250 GB has the two partitions, and about 60 GB of the HDD is in use. The destination drive is 240 GB. I used Gparted to ensure the partitioned size of the source is 20 GB smaller than the capacity of the destination.

I tried a local to local disk clone using basic mode, and using advanced mode with the [-icds option](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image/advanced/09-advanced-param.php) (and [here](http://www.seanwingert.com/blogs/clonezilla-clone-bigger-smaller-drive-eg-ssd)). None of the methods have worked. The first partition clones OK, but the second partition fails because the destination drive is too small.

How do I clone given basic and advanced mode has failed?

Comment: You need to either specifically indicated the starting and ending sector index or shrink  the source partition or indicate the sectors from the image itself to restore.  Your choice.  Hopefully you won't chew my face off for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The source HDD is 250 GB has the two partitions, and about 60 GB of the HDD is in use. The destination drive is 240 GB. I used Gparted to ensure the partitioned size of the source is 20 GB smaller than the capacity of the destination.

In this case, add 20GB of slack space for the shrink was not enough. I had to add more slack space at 40GB. With 40GB of slack I was able to perform the clone.

The odd thing was, I looked at the partitions after the clone using [GParted](http://gparted.org/). GParted shows there is unused space available in the second partition of the new drive. I'm guessing Clonezilla has a small math bug somewhere, and the problem did not really exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Macrium Reflect free for 4-5 years now and highly recommend it.
Download it, run it, check the system reserved and the C drive, click "Clone this disk.., and follow your nose....

If you're using partition C for the system and D for data (my recommendation), you can resize C after cloning using the Windows Disk manager. If you move all your user folders using the location tab - you can't move appdata (actually you can but it's a bad idea), I would recommend dividing it with 100GB on C. Then move your folders simply by changing the C to a D. That way you will have the same folder structure on D.

When you're finished, use Reflect to create an image - a lot easier than reinstalling when things go wrong.
You will also need to create a recovery drive on a USB device.
You can create the image on the D drive and it will restore from there but that doesn't help if the drive dies. It won't restore from a network device either. It needs to be on a USB drive.

Have fun.